Lost Biometric Residence Permit (BRP), passport expired, what to do?
I am a South African citizen currently in the UK on an ancestral visa. Since I am not intending to return to my home country I allowed my passport to lapse (but I still have it). Last week I travelled to London and upon returning home, realised that I had lost my BRP (which I carry with me at all times) while in the capital. I went to apply for a replacement via the gov.uk website but it does not allow me to do so with an expired passport, what can I do?

You can't renew if it's already expired, you have to do a whole new application which I'm really hoping to avoid...

You will need a valid passport either way, do it ASAP

It-expired passport renewal (ie, new application) is an unbelievable hassle.

Don't you ever plan on traveling outside the UK? If applying for a new passport is a hassle, surely that is an argument in favor of doing it now, rather than on short notice if you need it to travel somewhere.

For those who (like me) are not familiar with the term, BRP stands for Biometric Residence Permit.

Thanks, @JanusBahsJacquet, I presumed the "B" was for "British". I do appreciate the clarification.

You may actually be able to skip applying for a new BRP due to the implementation of the new eVisa system. If you have your lost BRP details you may be able to use those to create a UKVI account and transfer your status to digital. However, if you want to travel before the end of the year, since you are a visa national, you'll need to renew your passport and get a new BRP.
By law, you must report your BRP as lost within 3 months of losing it (even if you cannot apply for a replacement due to not having a valid passport)

Renew your passport. Then apply for replacement.
